# Can I say 'If you don't like me, then don't put coffee for me!'?

Tags: phrase-request, phrases, indian-english

Recently my friend from another country stated this phrase

> If you don't like me, then don't put coffee for me!.

I was puzzled when I heard it for first time, then I asked him what the meaning of it was, and he said it meant

> If you don't like me, then don't prepare me food along with yours.

Is this phrase correct? How could one create more phrases like this?

Comment: What country was he from?

Comment: indian, but currently stay in netherlands for educational.

Comment: It not quite correct-  one does not "*put*" coffee. It could be, "Then don't *make me coffee*". Or, "Then don't *serve me coffee.*". Or, "don't *share your coffee with me.*"

Comment: He was basically saying, "If you don't like me, don't do what I like." So, if you like him... I think you know what he wanted you to do for him. :-)

Answer (score 2):

It's not correct. We can say:

> If you don't like me, (then) don't make coffee for me.

Comment: but normally how to create an phrase?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible it's a quirk of Indian English.

Rare but also acceptable phrasings would also be

> If you don't like me, (then) don't put out coffee for me.
>
> If you don't like me, (then) don't put on coffee for me.

put out = offer [don't offer me refreshments]

put on = prepare/heat/make [again, don't make coffee for me]